# Can annotation view show in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have create a alert function in iOS for when distance greater than 200 meters. And it did pop-up. But I wonder if I can put annotation view in that alert box that similar to Apple ID sign in requested view. I don't know how to do that. I attached my code below.

```
 func creatAlert (title:String, message:String, locations: [[String : Any]]) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert .addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Yes")
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("No")
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            for location in locations {
                let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotations.title = location["title"] as? String
                annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (location["latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees)!, longitude: (location["longtitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees)!)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)
            }
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And I attached the screenshot picture. The map doesn't show on the alert box.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @matt. Problem solved.